# Neutralizing or Migitating ARP spoofing once detected

Tags: wifi, attack-prevention, arp-spoofing, protection, countermeasure

I've seen a few methods to detect ARP Spoofing attacks through code(such as [this](http://www.vivekramachandran.com/docs/arp-spoofing.pdf)), and ways to defend against these attacks through software and switches (like [arp spoofing protection on LAN](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20147/arp-spoofing-protection-on-lan)). How would I prevent arp spoofing with my own code(conceptually)? I wasn't sure if this would be better for Stackoverflow or this site.

**EDIT:**
I don't care so much about any specific language, psuedocode would be great but I'm also fine with just the conceptual side of things.

Comment: what kind of code?  I'm not sure I understand the question since most high level code won't have much to do with frame-level network traffic?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I don't care so much about any specific language, psuedocode would be great if possible.

Comment: ... you mean re-implementing arp spoofing detection or prevention?  Any kind of solution that alerts when there are multiple mac addresses claiming to be a particular IP or even flagging changes; also solutions that try to lock down entries to a 'known good' state.

Comment: pacifist, I'm hoping for prevention, is there any reliable way to prevent this other than just alerting the user or disconnecting from the network?

Comment: its fairly system dependent but anything that stops your machine using malicious routes would do the trick.  In practice things change so such a system usually becomes less practical if someone really did change ports or interfaces in a way that affects arp legitimately.